# How to show timer icon before text in Material-UI CardHeader subtitle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a post and I am showing time like a few seconds ago, 2mins ago, an hour ago etc but I want to show a clock icon before the string.

I tried below solution but it always shows [object object] a few seconds ago. Here Time is material UI icon.

```
  let date = `${<Time />} a few seconds ago`;
  <CardHeader
                  title={this.props.userName}
                  subtitle={date}
                  subtitleStyle={{ fontSize: 10}}
                  style={myTheme.cardHeaderStyle}
                  titleStyle={myTheme.contentStyle}
                  subtitleColor="#90949c"
  />
```

So how can I show the icon before text?

Note: I am using material-UI v0 version.

Answer (score 0):

passing time like this "let date = `${<Time />} a few seconds ago`;" is taking time component as a object. You can try below method.

```
let date = `${<Time />} a few seconds ago`;
const TimeIcon = () => {<h3><Time /> a few seconds ago</h3>}

  <CardHeader
                  title={this.props.userName}
                  subtitle={children}
                  subtitleStyle={{ fontSize: 10}}
                  style={myTheme.cardHeaderStyle}
                  titleStyle={myTheme.contentStyle}
                  subtitleColor="#90949c"
  >
 <TimeIcon />
</ CardHeader>
```